# iphone - Check whether call can be placed or not

Tags: iphone, call

I googled a lot and found that its not possible to find whether operator's signal is present or not. But is there valid API to find whether I can place a call or not?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any method to determine the carrier signal. If all else fails, there's likely a hackish way to do it by grabbing a screenshot and analyzing the upper-left corner. That said...

You might want to dig into CoreTelephony, as there might be something in there. [`CTCall callState]`? (I'm not familiar enough with it to say...).

To find out if the the telephone URL can be used (i.e. `tel:8005551212`):

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication: canOpenURL:telURL])
{
    // your code here
}
```

This will at least help determine if the user's on a phone capable device.

Using `openURL:` will return YES, even when in Airplane Mode.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can check if the operator signal is present but you can check if you can actually place a call:

```
NSURL *phoneNumberURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://004412345"];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneNumberURL] == YES) {
  ...
}
```